# HTML input control value disappears when add PADDING

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need CSS help on formatting this **BID VALUE** text box (input element) (See in Picture 1)
**Picture 1**
[image]
Product link is [here](https://innvex.innfix.co.tz/product/front-damaged-2000-patrol/)

When I make text box wider via Padding the text value inside the box is disappearing (Get hidden probably) I can't find where I'm doing wrong.

I have duplicated them so you can understand my problem, If you look on the photo above I have labeled Number 1 & 2, they both have same ID and other properties **BUT**

**BID VALUE Number 1** have the following custom CSS

```
input[name="bid_value"]
{
  width:auto;
  padding: 4px 120px 5px 31px;
  margin: 2px 11px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: left;
    
}
```

**BID VALUE Number 2** doesn't have any custom CSS its by default that way, It does not show the current BID VALUES clear (all value figures) that's why I want it to be a little big but if i do that (referring BID VALUE 1) the value is disappearing, Any advice on where I'm doing wrong?

**I wish my BID VALUE text box above to be like this format here in **Picture 2****
[image]
Its link is [here](https://wpgenie.org/woocommerce-simple-auctions/product/shadow-box-mexican-nicho-miniature-handmade-folk-art-future/)

Looking forward to hear from you guys on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for choosing a correct answer to this question. Please also consider upvoting any answers that might not have been correct but provided useful information.  It is allowable to upvote and checkmark the same answer. Doing so will acknowledge more answers, which is helpful to the StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using `width: auto`, add `!important` to overwrite *existing* CSS (i.e. `width: 3.631em;` in a rule for `.woocommerce .quantity .qty`), otherwise your padding will fill the whole input field.

Comment: Lol thank you a lot, the `!important` tag did the magic, be blessed buddy

Answer (score 0):

If the L/R (width) padding leaves no room for the text at the chosen font size, the text will not be displayed.

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
let pwid = 10;
$('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  pwid = pwid += 20;
  $('input').style.paddingLeft = `${pwid}px`;
  $('input').style.paddingRight = `${pwid}px`;
  $('aside').innerHTML = `Control Width: 130px<br>L/R Padding: ${pwid}px`;
});
```

```css
input{width:130px;padding:10px;box-sizing:border-box;margin-bottom:20px;}
button{padding:7px 10px;background:#ccc;border:1px solid #ccccccCC;border-radius:4px;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Merry Christmas" />
<div><button>Add 20px to Padding Width</button></div>
<aside></aside>
```

Solution: Use font-size instead of padding to make the text easier to see. If the input field is not growing with the text, then change the `width` and/or `max-width` values on the input (text) box to be either "auto" or "unset".

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment but i tried early to make font-size a bit smaller but it did not workout, i have tried the max-width also as you suggested but no any change  ;(